# How to optimize and clean these loops?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm writing a project with Laravel.i have a loop with a lot of condition like this:

```
  foreach ($transactionsGroupBys as $transactionsGroupBy) {

        if ($this->checkExistSettlement($transactionsGroupBy, Carbon::today())) {
            $this->setErrorLog('This settlement has already been created', $transactionsGroupBy);
            continue;
        }

        try {

            if ($this->doChunk()) {

                $transactions = $this->getTransactions($transactionsGroupBy);
                $maxAmountSettle = $this->configRepository->find('transaction_chunk:PUBLIC')->value;
                $transactionChunk = app(ChunkTransaction::class)->chunk($transactions, $maxAmountSettle);

                foreach ($transactionChunk as $chunk) {
                    $transactionsIds = collect($chunk->transactions)->pluck('id')->toArray();
                    $settlements[] = $this->insertSettlement($chunk->transactions_group_by, $transactionsIds)->toArray();
                    $this->setInfoLog("Created $counter/$countSettlements settlement", $chunk->transactions_group_by);
                }

            } else {

                $transactions = $this->getTransactions($transactionsGroupBy, ['id']);
                $transactionsIds = $transactions ? collect($transactions)->pluck('id')->toArray() : [];

                $settlements[] = $this->insertSettlement($transactionsGroupBy, $transactionsIds)->toArray();
                $this->setInfoLog("Created $counter/$countSettlements settlement", $transactionsGroupBy);
            }

            $counter += 1;

        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->setErrorLog($exception->getMessage());
            continue;
        }

    }
```

i am checking `$this->doChunk()` and if true, run other loop. i feel this code is very Complicated and i have duplicated code. i need new pattern for Solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's ok.

One point that can be corrected is - remove `try {} catch {}` block and rewrite it using Laravel ExceptionHandler.

Other way is split this method and put every branch in big `if` statement into separate methods, then rewrite `if` to thernary operator.

Also you can rewrite `foreach` with `array_reduce` to reduce the complexity of the code, in relation to "counter"